# where to change image in summary on linkedin

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, meta-tags

When I past mt website link into summary section(via Add Link) I see wrong image

where can I change that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this and it worked. It took hours for propogation but now I see right image.

```
 <meta itemprop="image" content="logo.png">
```